# Applying a class more programmatically

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

My project renders a lot of tables with financial data, and one of the requirements is that positive numbers are green and negative numbers are red (along with a couple of other stylizations).  I have classes for doing this ("gain" and "loss"), and I know that I can apply them conditionally with `ng-class`, but the repetitiveness of doing so makes me feel that perhaps there might be a way similar to a filter where I can just apply the check repeatedly, without having to actually spell it out every time.

I could cheat and use a filter to wrap the output in a span with the class, but that would effectively break filter chaining, so I won't be doing that.

A section of the table might look like:

```
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat="month in report" ng-class="{ loss : month.gross < 0, gain: month.gross > 0 }">{{ month.gross | currency }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat="month in report" ng-class="{ loss : month.net < 0, gain: month.net > 0 }">{{ month.net | currency }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat="month in report" ng-class="{ loss : month.profit < 0, gain: month.profit > 0 }">{{ month.profit | currency }}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to abstract out the `ng-class="{ loss: x < 0, gain: x > 0 }"` or am I just stuck repeating it? I have similar cases where I'm checking even more than two cases, but this is definitely the more common situation.

Comment: well, what you could do is preprocess the results and generate the class name before it hits the view. This way you could do something like month.classToUse = 'gain' or month.classToUse = 'loss'. But this would barely be any saving as angular will still create watchers to check for changes.

Comment: I'm not sure how it would be done but isn't this a scenario for directive usage?

Comment: Yep sounds like you're looking for a directive.

Comment: directives would be even more costly than a simple watcher. In terms of processing.

Comment: What you also want to look into is angular bind-once: https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce , this prevents angular from creating watchers, hence you will save some processing.

Comment: @alou - I'm only starting to feel that I'm getting the hang of Angular, so I've only been using directives as blocks of my application - didn't even occur to me to use them to just apply a class, I confess. I'll give it a spin and see whether they're worth the overhead in this case (both performance and time spent). I think it might be helpful to just be able to add an attribute to accomplish this, though.

Comment: @EliteOctagon - I think I see what you're saying about the preprocessor, but it seems to me that will generally add more confusion, and also remove some of the presentation logic away from the display. I'll try a directive and see what happens with it. Thanks for the bindonce link - I'll check that out as well. I appreciate the comments.